# Request field validation not performed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-validator

I'm conducting tests to validate when a field in a request body is not received, and I expect an exception to be thrown. However, Spring doesn't even return the generic error. I've generated classes from an `OpenAPI` contract and am reusing the generated controller methods. Here are the details:

Generated Controller:

```
@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen")
@Validated
@Tag(name = "user", description = "Operations about user")
public interface UserApi {

    @Operation(
        operationId = "createUser",
        summary = "Create user",
        description = "This can only be done by the logged-in user.",
        tags = { "user" },
        responses = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "default", description = "successful operation", content = {
                @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = User.class)),
                @Content(mediaType = "application/xml", schema = @Schema(implementation = User.class))
            })
        }
    )
    @RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        value = "/user",
        produces = { "application/json", "application/xml" },
        consumes = { "application/json", "application/xml", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
    )
    ResponseEntity<User> createUser(
        @Parameter(name = "User", description = "Created user object", required = true) @Valid @RequestBody User user
    );
}
```

Generated Entity:

```
@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen")
public class User {
  ...
  private String documentNumber;
  ...
  public User documentNumber(String documentNumber) {
    this.documentNumber = documentNumber;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get documentNumber
   * @return documentNumber
  */
  @NotNull 
  @Schema(name = "documentNumber", example = "John", requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.REQUIRED)
  @JsonProperty("documentNumber")
  public String getDocumentNumber() {
    return documentNumber;
  }

  public void setDocumentNumber(String documentNumber) {
    this.documentNumber = documentNumber;
  }

  ...
}
```

Controller Created by Me:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class UserController implements UserApi {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final MapperUtils mapperUtils;

    @Override
    @PostMapping(
        value = "/user",
        produces = { "application/json" }
    )
    public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(User user) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(mapperUtils.mapRequestToUser(mapperUtils.mapUserToResponse(user)));
    }
}
```

Entity Created by Me:

```
@Data
@Table(name = "USUARIO")
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserEntity {
      @Id
      private Long id;
      private String name;
      private String documentNumber;
      private String email;
      private Integer state;
}
```

As you can see, in the generated entity, the `documentNumber` field is marked as required with the `@NotNull` annotation. Also, in the generated controller, the `@Valid` and `@Validated` annotations are present. Therefore, it should return a validation error. However, the flow continues, and it records the data I send, including the null values. What is happening? Dependencies File Shared.

```
<!-- XML content provided for Maven POM file -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <!-- Project information -->
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <!-- Spring Boot parent -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-spring-maven</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo-spring-maven</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <!-- Project properties including OpenAPI generator version, Swagger version, Jackson version, etc. -->
    <properties>
        <openapi-generator.version>6.6.0</openapi-generator.version>
        <openapi.package.api>org.example.api.spec.controller</openapi.package.api>
        <openapi.package.model>org.example.api.spec.dto</openapi.package.model>
        <swagger.annotations.version>2.2.14</swagger.annotations.version>
        <jackson-nullable.version>0.2.6</jackson-nullable.version>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <!-- Project dependencies including Spring Boot, H2 database, validation-api, Swagger, OpenAPI tools, etc. -->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot Web starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- H2 Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Validation API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Swagger Annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.annotations.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- OpenAPI tools Jackson Databind Nullable -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-nullable.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JavaX Annotation API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot Data JPA starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot Validation starter with exclusions for validation-api and javax.annotation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot Webflux starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ModelMapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SpringDoc OpenAPI starter for WebMVC UI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <!-- Maven build configuration including Spring Boot and OpenAPI generator plugins -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Spring Boot Maven Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!-- OpenAPI Generator Maven Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-api-code</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- OpenAPI YAML specification file path -->
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <!-- Various configuration options for code generation -->
                            <generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <strictSpec>true</strictSpec>
                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                            <!-- Controller exceptions, interface-only, skip default interface, and more -->
                            <configOptions>
                                <!-- Controller exceptions -->
                                <controllerThrowsExceptions>java.io.IOException,com.example.NotFoundException</controllerThrowsExceptions>
                                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                                <skipDefaultInterface>true</skipDefaultInterface>
                                <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                                <useClassLevelBeanValidation>false</useClassLevelBeanValidation>
                                <useTags>true</useTags>
                                <java17>true</java17>
                                <useOptional>false</useOptional>
                                <library>spring-boot</library>
                                <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
                                <dateLibrary>java17</dateLibrary>
                                <bigDecimalAsString>true</bigDecimalAsString>
                                <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                                <apiPackage>${openapi.package.api}</apiPackage>
                                <modelPackage>${openapi.package.model}</modelPackage>
                            </configOptions>
                            <!-- Type mappings and import mappings -->
                            <typeMappings>
                                <typeMapping>OffsetDateTime=LocalDateTime</typeMapping>
                            </typeMappings>
                            <importMappings>
                                <importMapping>java.time.OffsetDateTime=java.time.LocalDateTime</importMapping>
                            </importMappings>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I only include `hibernate-validator` and it works fine. Not really sure why you're including all the javax dependencies though. Not to mention including WebMvc and Webflux in the same project. That will cause you some potential issues.

Comment: @SledgeHammer Could you please tell me which dependencies should be maintained? I have webflux because later I will add reactive programming.

Comment: If you mix WebMvc & WebFlux starters, it will break anything that uses `@OnConditionalBean`, etc. type annotations. Spring Boot 3 uses Jakarta servlets, not Javax. I only have the `hibernate-validator` for validation wise.

Comment: @SledgeHammer , I cannot remove `javax.validation`, since when generating the classes from OpenApi they use `@NotNull`, etc. I just ran the test keeping the dependency I mentioned and placing the hibernate one, and it still doesn't throw the exception.

Comment: You're mixing different platforms, namespaces and webmvc/webflux :). I use `org.springframework.lang.NonNull` in my code. Why are you using the OpenApi generator?  Just to map `OffsetDateTime` to `LocalDateTime` in the schema? Why don't you want to use `OffsetDateTime`? That's really the one you should be using. It doesn't matter to callers as it will get mapped to a `String` in Swagger anyways. Plus, your `LocalDateTime` isn't Bob's `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: P.S. you don't use `ResponseEntity<T>` any more either. That's old school :). Just return `User`. If you need to return an error, you just throw a `ResponseStatusException` from the controller and Spring does the rest.

Comment: wait, you're defining YOUR Swagger spec by hand? Or is that a 3rd party one?

Comment: Also, you can't "add reactive programming" to webmvc. It's one or the other. WebMvc runs on Tomcat (in general) and Webflux runs on Netty (in general).

Comment: Your dependencies are a mess of incompatible dependencies, incompatible with Spring Boot 3. Remove the `validation-api`, `hibernate-validator` and all the `excludes` you have on `spring-boot-starter-*` dependencies. Those starters include all you need (use `spring-boot-starter-validation`). If that leads to an issue with the OpenAPI generator use a newer version or instruct it to use Jakarta Validation instead of Java Validation.

Answer (score 1):

Your dependencies, as well as your configuration, are a mess of incompatible versions. Incompatible with each other and with Spring Boot.

**PRO-TIP**: As soon as you are starting to add `excludes` to Spring Boot Starter, take your hands of the keyboard, rollback your chair and rethink. Because then you are doing it wrong!

First fix your dependencies.

```xml
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Boot Web starter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- H2 Database -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Swagger Annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger.annotations.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- OpenAPI tools Jackson Databind Nullable -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-nullable.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Next instruct your OpenAPI generator to use [JakartaEE instead of JavaEE](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/java/). For this add the `useJakartaEe` with value `true` to the `configOptions` of your `openapi-generator-maven-plugin`.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-api-code</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- OpenAPI YAML specification file path -->
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
                <!-- Various configuration options for code generation -->
                <generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>
                <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                <strictSpec>true</strictSpec>
                <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                <!-- Controller exceptions, interface-only, skip default interface, and more -->
                <configOptions>
                    <!-- Controller exceptions -->
                    <controllerThrowsExceptions>java.io.IOException,com.example.NotFoundException</controllerThrowsExceptions>
                    <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                    <skipDefaultInterface>true</skipDefaultInterface>
                    <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                    <useClassLevelBeanValidation>false</useClassLevelBeanValidation>
                    <useTags>true</useTags>
                    <java17>true</java17>
                    <useOptional>false</useOptional>
                    <library>spring-boot</library>
                    <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
                    <dateLibrary>java17</dateLibrary>
                    <bigDecimalAsString>true</bigDecimalAsString>
                    <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                    <apiPackage>${openapi.package.api}</apiPackage>
                    <modelPackage>${openapi.package.model}</modelPackage>
                    <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
                </configOptions>
                <!-- Type mappings and import mappings -->
                <typeMappings>
                    <typeMapping>OffsetDateTime=LocalDateTime</typeMapping>
                </typeMappings>
                <importMappings>
                    <importMapping>java.time.OffsetDateTime=java.time.LocalDateTime</importMapping>
                </importMappings>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Finally remove the `@Validated` from your controller class only leave the `@Valid` on the method parameter. The `@Validated` on the method serves a different purpose and can (and will) lead to some surprising results.

Comment: Works. When I do not send a field in the body, it returns a "400 bad request" and I imagine that it is generic because in the @NotNull of the generated class there is no message. How could a message be placed, since it cannot be modified directly because it is a generated class?

Comment: You can register a specific message using I18N (Internationalization in Spring Boot) by providing a specific key with a message. I'm however not sure which key will be generated, I suspect something like `<your-class-name>.NotNull` if you put that with a message or the general `NotNull` with a message in a `messages.properties` it should take that.